# Angular factory not loading data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm trying to move http calls to angular factory but not sure why data not loaded. The issue is related to the `customersController`, for now I load data locally but eventually will move it to `$http`

```
app.factory('apiFactory', ["apiFactory", "$http", (apiFactory, $http) ->
  factory = {}
  customers = [
    { name: 'Apple', city: 'Cupertino' },
    { name: 'Google', city: 'SF' }
  ]
  factory.getCustomers ->
    customers
])
```

Here is Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/itYnyzg2uS5xc6MJIIkE?p=preview

Comment: Dude you should have told me you were going to make this another question. I answered it (from your comment in the other post) an hour ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you were facing a circular reference.

- You don't need `apiFActory` while defining `apiFactory`, hence circular reference.
- Factory/Service should produce an API to be used by controller

Pardon my coffee script, if I am wrong anywhere. I tried to co-relate it to JavaScript for the API method. I may be wrong with the sytnax.

```
app.factory('apiFactory', ["$http", ($http) ->
  factory = {}
  customers = [
    { name: 'Apple', city: 'Cupertino' },
    { name: 'Google', city: 'SF' },
    { name: 'Mont Blanc', city: 'Paris' }
  ]

  return {
    getCustomers: () ->
      customers
  }
])
```

Refer this modified version of [<kbd>**PLUNKR**</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/lo82elAWhaIViWCKHwVA?p=preview)